# NoClassDefFounderError External jar file

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

Hey I'm Having this problem in android project! I have read so many topics but none of them helps!

I'm so close to the ackward moment that you wanna kill yourself but you dont have the proper tool!
please somebody help

I am Using Eclipse

I have added the jar file in the libs forder.

I have added in the build path the jar from the lib folder.

I have done all of the things that has been mentioned!

But still When I'm using a class from jar file I get NoClassDefFounderError !

If you have anything please let me know that would be appreciated a lot .
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post some part of your code that could interest persons who want to help you ?

Comment: The Code is nothing special just calling a class from a jar from!

Comment: have you put the jar in lib or libs? It needs to be put into libs! or else you need to go to "configure build path.."->"Order and Export" and mark the checkbox next to your jar file.

Comment: It is libs already! I found rhia problem mentioned before! But thats not the case

Comment: @Renard: I don't think that is a problem of configuring build path, because he had a run time exception not a compile one.  try to verify your jar.

Comment: Martin is probably right! I think java versions are diffrent! Because its a new technology

Comment: What is your java version? try to run `java -version` in windows/linux command line. or add  `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` to your main class.

Comment: @IMAnis_tn as of ADT 17 jars dont get packaged into the apk if they are not inside the libs folder even when they are in the build path. So if they are for example in folder lib one would get a runtime exception while the code compiles just fine. now iam really asking myself how a jvm version can relate to android dalvik..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the JVM version you are using is older than the java compiler version used to compile the class files in the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You jar file must be in libs folder OR in your build path but not both.

When you go to the properties of your project, and go to the build path options, does the lib is check in "Order and Export" (in case of your jar is added in build path).

Moreover, have you import the class in your code (CTRL+SHIFT+O or CMD+SHIFT+O) ?

Comment: There is no judgment in my post so stay cool. Sometimes, a bug appears because we forgot a simple thing !